# angular 2 trigger 'click' using jquery not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create a application with angular 2,i have an `<a>` tag and using `("click") event`.I want when an component rendering finished my a tag trigger click using jquery.But not working !
here is my .HTML code :

```
     <a href="" id="all_m" ('click')="test($event)"></a>
```

in my another component : 
        export class inside_group_page implements OnInit{

```
        ngOnInit(){
             jQuery("#all_m").trigger("click");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not use jquery with ng2

```
@Component({
   selector: 'inside-page-group',
   template: `<a #all_m href="" ('click')="test($event)"></a>`
}
export class InsideGroupPage {
   @ViewChild('all_m')
   private allMElementRef;

   constructor(@Inject(Renderer) private renderer: Renderer){
   }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
       this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.allMElementRef.nativeElement, 'click', []);
   }
}
```